# Class scrlttr2: Eliminate space between refvpos and date

Tags: spacing, scrlttr2

There is a small space between where `visualize.lco` (loaded with command `\LoadLetterOption{visualize}`) indicates is the top of the refline, and where text in the refline actually appears. How can I get rid of this?

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}

\setkomavar{date}{\fbox{11/01/2011}}

\showfields{address,refline}
\setshowstyle{edges}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Dr.~Leo Lion\\Fordstan University}
  \opening{Dear Sir,}
  This is a test.
  \closing{Sincerely yours}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of what this code produces]

Comment: It is to me, at least :) I was able to hack something together that involving changing the definition of the letter environment so that `refvpos` is `toaddrvpos` + the height of the toaddr area + `0.89\baselineskip` but I don't know why 0.89. Would prefer a more sustainable, elegant, and informed solution.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. But I want to exactly get rid of the actual space between refvpos and date, not change the way the visualization works.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this happens, but it looks like the effect is because the date takes up an entire `\baselineskip` rather than just the cap-height. So to get the top of the text to be placed exactly at the desired position, I offset `\refvpos` from what I actually wanted:

``\newlength{\capheight}\setlength{\capheight}{\fontcharht\font`X}
\setplength{refvpos}{\dimexpr<where I actually want refline>-\baselineskip+\capheight\relax}``

Answer (score 2):

Well, in file `visualize.lco` you can find the definition of command `\showfield@refline}`  to display the location of the used refline by edges or lines.

At the end of this definition you can find the command

```
\showfield{\useplength{refhpos}}{\useplength{refvpos}}%
          {\useplength{refwidth}}{-1.5\baselineskip}%
```

to display the location of the refline.  To change the position in verticaly position you need to change the second parameter `\useplength{refvpos}` to  for example `1.01\useplength{refvpos}` ...

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address,refline}
\setshowstyle{edges}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\showfield@refline}{%
  \begingroup
    \ifdim\useplength{refwidth}=\z@
      \if@refwide
        \@setplength{refwidth}{\paperwidth}%
        \ifdim \useplength{toaddrhpos}>\z@
          \@setplength{refhpos}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}%
        \else
          \@setplength[-]{refhpos}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}%
        \fi
        \@addtoplength[-2]{refwidth}{\useplength{refhpos}}%
      \else
        \@setplength{refwidth}{\textwidth}%
        \@setplength{refhpos}{\oddsidemargin}%
        \@addtoplength{refhpos}{1in}%
      \fi
    \else\ifdim\useplength{refhpos}=\z@
        \begingroup
          \setlength\@tempdima{\textwidth}%
          \addtolengthplength[-]{\@tempdima}{refwidth}%
          \setlength\@tempdimb{\oddsidemargin}%
          \addtolength\@tempdimb{1in}%
          \setlength{\@tempdimc}{\paperwidth}%
          \addtolength{\@tempdimc}{-\textwidth}%
          \divide\@tempdimb by 32768\relax
          \divide\@tempdimc by 32768\relax
          \ifdim\@tempdimc=\z@\else
            \multiply\@tempdima by\@tempdimb
            \divide\@tempdima by\@tempdimc
          \fi
          \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\endgroup
            \noexpand\@setplength{refhpos}{\the\@tempdima}}%
        \@tempa
    \fi\fi
    \showfield{\useplength{refhpos}}{1.01\useplength{refvpos}}% <=======
              {\useplength{refwidth}}{-1.5\baselineskip}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\setkomavar{date}{\fbox{11/01/2011 Qyf}}

%\setkomavar{myref}{201807/Q}
\setkomavar{subject}{Question}
\setkomavar{place}{Capital city}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Dr.~Leo Lion\\Fordstan University}
  \opening{Dear Sir,}
  This is a test.
  \closing{Sincerely yours}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image]

But at last I think it is not relevant, because the lines or edges to visualize the refline position are displayed without changing the position of the refline.  It is only a visualisation and with a little distance between the lines/edges and your box the edges/lines can be seen better ...